# my javascript in external html is not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, external

ok so in order here is my code

**/* index.html */**

```
<!-- jQuery Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdr.host22.com/scripts/li.js"></script>
    <link href="http://tdr.host22.com/scripts/tdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Div Layout -->
    <div id="container">
     <div id="dp">my DP here</div>
     <div id="hrefs">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="about">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a id="shop">My Shop / Wishlist</a></li>
        <li><a id="friend">My Friends</a></li>
        <li><a id="vids">Wicked Videos</a></li>
        <li><a id="music">Music Playlist</a></li>
        <li><a id="pics">My Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a id="ranks">My Rankings</a></li>
        <li><a id="stuff">Random Stuff</a></li>
        <li><a id="read">Read Messages</a></li>
        <li><a id="leave">Leave a Message</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="content">
     TDR Content
      <div id="loading">  
       <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />  
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

**/* li.js */**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //References
 var sections = $("#menu a");
 var loading = $("#loading");
 var content = $("#content");

 //Manage click events
 sections.click(function(){
  //show the loading bar
  showLoading();
  //load selected section
  switch(this.id){
   case "home":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #home_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   case "about":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #aboutme_panel", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   case "shop":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #shop_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   case "friend":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #friend_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   case "vids":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #vids_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   case "music":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #music_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   case "pics":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #pics_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   case "ranks":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #ranks_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   case "stuff":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #stuff_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   case "read":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #read_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   case "leave":
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #leave_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
    break;
   default:
    //hide loading bar if there is no selected section
    hideLoading();
    break;
  }
 });

 //show loading bar
 function showLoading(){
  loading
   .css({visibility:"visible"})
   .css({opacity:"1"})
   .css({display:"block"})
  ;
 }
 //hide loading bar
 function hideLoading(){
  loading.fadeTo(1000, 0);
 };
});
```

**/* sections.html */**

```
<div id="home_section">
Home haha
</div>
<!-- About Us -->
<div id="about_section">  
<script type='text/javascript'><!--
imvu_avatar_name = "TheDarkRaver";
imvu_panel_name = "aboutme_panel";
imvu_section_name = "mp_left";
imvu_panel_width = 590;
imvu_panel_height = 459;
//--></script>
</div>
```

**/* tdr.css */**

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
/******* GENERAL RESET *******/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em,
font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody,
 tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
border: 0pt none;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
font-style: inherit;
font-weight: inherit;
margin: 0pt;
padding: 0pt;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/*Removing Bullets*/
#menu {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:0;
}
#menu li { 
list-style-type:none; 
display: inline;
} 
/*Menu Link Style */
#menu a, #menu a:visited {
  position:relative; /* ADDED */
  display:block;
  width:9em;
  cursor: crosshair;
  border:1px solid orange;
  font-family:cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size:0.7em;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  background:transparent;
  color:orange;
  padding:0.25em;
}
#menu a:hover {
 color:red;
 border:1px solid red;
}
#container {
 position:relative;
 width: 700px;
 height:400px;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 1px;
 border-color:orange;
 border-style: dotted;
 margin: 0pt auto;
}
#hrefs {
 width:0px;
}
#content {
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:9.8em;
 width:580px;
 height:100%;
 border:1px solid #0066CC;
 background-color:transparent;
 background-image:  url("../images/cont.png");
 background-repeat: repeat;
 overflow: auto;
 color: #000000;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 font-size: 12px;
}
#dp {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 left:0px;
}
#loading{  
     text-align: center;  
     visibility: hidden;  
}  
.clear{
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: I have added it it just isn't posted for some reason i'm new to this site so far i don't like how the display code script works in the WYSIWYG  i fixed the errors that were in while i was trouble shooting so it's back to it's "broken completed state"

Comment: Ok so now the code is correct again but if you check out http://tdr.host22.com/ and click about me you will notice it loads the whole site inside the div instead of loading the div #about_section in sections.html ...

Comment: ok fixed that issue but now it's doing the original issues loading the Div but blank no javascript.

Comment: so does noone know :( that sucks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Nick said, you probably aren't including jQuery, are there any errors in Firebug or anything like that?

Also, you might want to consider replacing most of your huge `switch` with something more like:

```
content.slideUp();
content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #" + this.id + "_section", hideLoading);
content.slideDown();
```

*Edit:*
To be more clear about this last part, first go into your markup and change:

```
<li><a id="about">About Me</a></li>
```

into

```
<li><a id="aboutme">About Me</a></li>
```

This is because in your javascript you're showing a section called 'aboutme'... best to just keep the names matching.... then delete your entire `switch` and replace it with:

```
content.slideUp();
content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #" + this.id + "_section", hideLoading);
content.slideDown();
```

So the entire javascript portion of your code becomes (with some other improvements):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var sections = $("#menu a");
  var loading = $("#loading");
  var content = $("#content");

  function showLoading() {
    loading.css( {
      visibility: 'visible',
      opacity: 1,
      display: 'block'
    } );
  }

  function hideLoading(){
    loading.fadeTo(1000, 0);
  }

  sections.click( function() {
    showLoading();
    content.slideUp();
    content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #" + this.id + "_section", hideLoading);
    content.slideDown();
  } );
} );
```

As you can see, this code doesn't even need comments because it's so short and concise.

Also, reading through this, it seems you almost certainly have other problems... The animations wont happen the way you expect, `slideUp` is asynchronous meaning that it will start sliding up and then immediately load, you probably don't want this behavior so look into jQuery's method of chaining animations (via callbacks, see the docs for [`slideUp`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideUp), for example), or take a look at jQuery 1.4's [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method.

Comment: i'm new to JS so i have no idea how to do that

Comment: thanks duks i'll read up on the callbacks do u have any suggestion for loading the javascript tags in the dom instead of executing them when i click the link

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you loading jQuery anywhere...you have to include the library itself at some point before your code, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdr.host22.com/scripts/li.js"></script>
```

Comment: He is trying to load jQuery, but from google code (http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js). So it's trying to download it instead of providing the script.

Comment: @fudgey: He is now :)  There was no jQuery script reference when this was asked/answered :)

Comment: well i fixed all the code but as far as i can tell still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening http://tdr.host22.com/scripts/li.js in your browser? You should be able to downloade the file directly.

Maybe you accidentally enabled some user authentication on your scripts folder?

I would also recommend using a path without the domain name, i.e. /scripts/li.js, so that you don't have to change it when the site is moved to another domain.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript in **sections.html** is inside `<div id="about_section">`

`content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #home_section", hideLoading);` will only load `<div id="home_section">` from **sections.html**

To load the JavaScript from **sections.html** try this

```
content.load("http://tdr.host22.com/sections.html #about_section", hideLoading);
```

Comment: content.load("#aboutme_panel", hideLoading); isn't going to load anything.

was a test for calling a hidden div panel directly off the imvu homepage